# How to change all the values in the column in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to set the value in the data grid view if the column "is_active" have the value of 0 then it show "ACTIVE" not 0.

[image: This is the Data grid view and the values from the database]

MY CODE:

```
            Dim dt As DataTable
            dt = exec("select * from tbl_credentials where is_active = 1 and is_status = 2")

            If DataGridView1.Columns(3).ToString = 1 Then
                dt.Columns(3).value = "ACTIVE"
            End If

            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: You should use a combo box column instead of a text box column. Just like a regular `ComboBox` control, it can show text that is different to the underlying value it represents.

Answer (score 2):

use select CASE :

```
Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = exec("select username,password, CASE is_active WHEN 0 then 'ACTIVE' ELSE '' END from tbl_credentials")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```